# Ursina FirstPersonController Change Collider Not Working

Tags: python, 3d, camera, panda3d, ursina

## My Issue

I am using the `Panda3D` wrapper for `Python` to run some 1st person game tests. I would like the collider of the `ursina` camera type called the `FirstPersonController` to extend its collider over the sprite. I have tried (without really knowing how as there aren't many tutorials on Ursina) using a `BoxCollider()` but I didn't really get how to do it. Can anyone help me?

#### My Code

```
from ursina import *
from ursina.prefabs.first_person_controller import FirstPersonController



class Player(Entity):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(    # super() is used to access things from the inheriting class (in this case the Entity class)
            model = 'cube',
            color = color.red,
            parent = parent
        )
        
        
class Floor(Entity):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(
            model = 'cube',
            scale = (40, 3, 40),
            color = color.rgb(23, 45, 105),
            position = (0, -20, 0),
            collider = 'box'
        )




app = Ursina()

window.fps_counter.enabled = False
window.fullscreen = True



cam = FirstPersonController()
player = Player(cam)


floor = Floor()



def update():
    if held_keys['escape']:
        application.quit()

Sky()
app.run()
```

Please help, all suggestions are helpful!

Comment: what do you mean by extending the collider? avoiding clipping into other objects?

Comment: @JanWilamowski Well, the 1st Person Controller has a collider that stops it walking through walls, right? So, I would like to extend/move the origin of the 1st Person Controllers collider to a cube in front of it so that it will not walk through a wall when the cube encounters a wall. Run the code to see what I mean.

Comment: I did run the code but there aren't any objects other than the floor. So when I add a cube, I will see the player cube intersect (clip into) it. Do you want to avoid that or just move the camera back to have a 3rd person view?

Comment: I want to make it so the cube is the player (3rd person view), I figured that 1st person controller would be good for it as I can't work out how to look around with the mouse without it.

Comment: To make sure you saw the previous comment, I'll tag you, @JanWilamowski

Comment: I added an answer - please let me know if I didn't understand your problem correctly.

Comment: I haven't quite run it in my game project (I am doing a ANN framework project currently), but it looks way simpler than I thought. I presume you also mean that I should parent the camera to the player.

Comment: yes, just as it's done in your code snippet. No changes other than the ones in my answer are needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show a 3rd person perspective, you can move the global camera back:

```py
def to_first_person():
    camera.position = (0, 0, 0)

def to_third_person():
    camera.position = (0, 0, -3)
```

You could either do this once when loading the game or switch back and forth via keyboard inputs:

```py
def input(key):
    if key == '1':
        to_first_person()
    if key == '3':
        to_third_person()
```